# Namespace conflict when using 3rd party api in class

Tags: php, namespaces

There is something weird going on. I'm a novice with respect to php programming. 
I'm trying to use FirePHP but my question is actually not related to that tool directly.

The function `fb` you'll see below is part of FirePHP. My entry point is `Main.php`. The first `fb` call is executed without any problems but the second call (see `ExperController.php`) ,which gets triggered when `$ec->exper();` in `Main.php` is called, causes a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Controllers\FirePHP' not found in path-to-wp-directory\wp-content\mu-plugins\typerocket\app\Controllers\ExperController.php on line 12

Why is the runtime engine looking for the class `FirePHP` under that namespace (App\Controllers)? And why wasn't this an issue during the first `fb` call? There isn't any namespace defined in the FirePHP files at all. And my last but crucial question, how can I fix this without having to touch 3rd party files? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136737/unable-to-load-vendor-classes-from-other-namespace) is not a solution for my case since I'm not referencing / calling the mentioned class in my code!

Note: FirePHP is included via autoloader (provided by composer).

**Main.php:**

```
<?php

fb('Hello World!', FirePHP::INFO);

$req = new \TypeRocket\Http\Request();
$res = new \TypeRocket\Http\Response();
$ec = new \App\Controllers\ExperController($req, $res);
$ec->exper();
```

**ExperController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;


use TypeRocket\Controllers\Controller;

class ExperController extends Controller
{

    public function exper() {
        fb('Hello World!', FirePHP::INFO);
    }

}
```

Comment: The PHP looking for the `FirePHP` under the current namespace what you defined at the beginning of the `ExperController.php`. So you need to help the PHP and you need to define what class want to use from other namespace. You need to add another use line like the `use TypeRocket\Controllers\Controller;` just for the `FirePHP`. I suggest to use some PHP IDE what helps you with references and tell you if there is some missing references. And follow @user122293 suggestion and use composer if you do not use already. :)

Comment: but as stated, FirePHP hasn't defined any namespace in its files / classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you use any Dependency manager like composer??
when you call it from main somehow php can see where is FirePHP class is and everything works fine but when you try to access it inside a class in another folder you must define where the class is inside your controller , like how you defined where is controller class that you extend :

```
use TypeRocket\Controllers\Controller;
```

so add FirePHP class to your controller and everything will be ok then.

```
use Path\To\Class\FirePHP;
```

also if you did all and still not working you may try dump autoload;

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: thanks, since FirePHP has no namespace defined, just putting "use \FirePHP;" did the trick... even though it's annoying that I need to know which classes are used in those 3rd party files internally and that I need such explicit "use" calls. I guess it's how php is working -.-